Can we find curves with many rational points using linear algebra?
Probably this is impossible, but let us try.
Working over $\mathbb{Q}[x_1,...,x_n]$.
Let $T_i$ be $n$ sets of rationals with cardinality $B$.
Assume we are given $n-2$ linear equations $f_i$ which are linearly
independent and their $S$ solutions satisfy $x_i \in T_i$.
Define $F_i=\prod_{a \in T_i}(x_i -a)$.
Let $g=\sum_{1 \le i \le n} F_i$. $g$ vanishes at all solutions $S$
and $g \cup f_i$ in general defines a curve of genus depending
only on $B=\deg F_i$.
If $|S|$ is sufficiently larger than $B$, we will have a curve
with many rational points, which is an open problem (not counting
genus smaller than $2$).

Q1 Can we find $n-2$ equations with large $|S|$?

Experimentally we rediscovered the trivial bound of $B^2$ points.
There is nothing special in $n-2$, we can ask for $n-k$ and add
$k-1$ non-linear equations.

Negative answer implies systems of linear diophantine equations over the integers can't have too many small solutions, which will answer the question System of linear diophantine equations with many small solutions?
